# how to create static login pages in yii framework ?

Tags: yii

In yii framework,because I want to redirect login page before access to admin site so How can we create the login page which do not content the header,footer and manu ?

thankyou very much ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login controller, set the layout for the login page.

For example, your login controller having function for login called `dologin`

Then

```
public function actionDologin()
{
    $this->layout = 'login_template';
    //render login page 
}
```

If you are working in modules and your layout is outside the modules, then you can use as below.

```
$this->layout = '//layouts/login_template';
```

Comment: Welcome. Accepting solution will help others to find better solution :-)